# getElementById then calculate length

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

A fairly easy question I assume, but I'm only a beginner and I'm struggling to work this out for myself and I can't seem to find the answer on google.

I have a heading tag that I need to grab using javascript and then work out the length of, then edit the font size depending on the result.

Why is my code not working?

```
var titleElement = document.getElementById("myelement");

if(titleElement.length>10){
titleElement.style.fontSize = 16;
}
```

### EDIT / ADDITION

I can't get it to work, even after your kind suggestion to add .innerHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="titleLengthShow()">
<h1 id="myelement">dfg adg earsh aaerg eaag erg aergethj5 yetfgg eg d</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

function titleLengthShow(){
var titleElement = document.getElementById("myelement");

    if(titleElement.innerHTML.length>10){
        titleElement.style.fontSize = 16;
    }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `titleElement.innerHTML.length`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work :(

Comment: Figured it out! I was missing the value in pixels.

      titleElement.style.fontSize = "16px";

Comment: It's a shame that nobody noticed that before. -_-

Answer (score 3):

```
var titleElement = document.getElementById("myelement");

if(titleElement.innerHTML.length > 10){
  titleElement.style.fontSize = "16px";
}
```

should work. innerHTML gives you the containing text (actually html).

if you have formating inside your heading tag it will also count those formating tags. instead you can use .textContent instead of .innerHTML, although this won't work in older IEs. for older IE versions .innerText should work.

```
var length = (titleElement.textContent || titleElement.innerText ||
              title.innerHTML).length;
```

shoudl work for the common browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of `titleElement.innerHTML`.

I strongly suggest to look into jQuery to do such things.

Comment: Why do you _"strongly suggest to look into jQuery"_? You're aware jQuery uses JS's native `innerHTML`, right?

Comment: @cloggy - I strongly suggest you don't look into jQuery to do such things. You'll soon find yourself in a dependency hell of jQuery plugins.

Comment: Cerbus: Well, because it's so much easier to manipulate DOM elements. Yes, I'm aware that in this example it does not make a big difference. But I anticipate there is more that cloggy may want to do in the future with DOM elements. @cloggy: using jQuery does not contradict learning JavaScript.

Comment: @Bernhard: He's not trying to manipulate the DOM, he simply wants to get the content length of a element. **[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)**, man. jQuery teaches people to be lazy and careless about efficiency. If I had a penny for every time I saw someone not cache `$('#myElement')`, and using it often...

Comment: I do know the basics of jQuery already, and really want to get to grips with JS ;o)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if(titleElement.length>10){
titleElement.style.fontSize = 16;
}
```

to

```
if(titleElement.innerHTML.length> 10){
titleElement.style.fontSize = "16px";
}
```